# A standard for error handling and graceful shutdown of Node/Express server

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling, server, shutdown

Below is a basic script I usually use for my express servers. Specifically, I am looking for answers to the following questions: Is it needed to include SIGINT and SIGTERM process signal handlers in production? Do I need to actually include an uncaught exception handler? What about tracking and cleaning up sockets?  Do I use process.exit(), process.exit(0), or process.exit(1), and if so, where exactly and why?

```
var express = require('express');
var sockets = [];
process.on('SIGINT', cleanup);
process.on('SIGTERM', cleanup);
var port = 7000;
var app = express();
var server = app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log(`app listening on port ${port}`);
})
.on("connection", onConnection)
.on("listening", onListening)
.on("error", onError)
.on("close", onClose);


var cleanup = function () {
    server.close(function () {
        console.log("Closed out remaining connections.");
        process.exit();
    });
    sockets.forEach(function (socket) {
        socket.destroy();
    });

    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log("Could not close connections in time, forcing shut down");
        process.exit(1);
    }, 30 * 1000);
}

function onConnection(socket) {
  sockets.push(socket);
}

function onError(error) {
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') throw error;

  var bind = typeof port === 'string'? 'Pipe ' + port : 'Port ' + port;

  switch (error.code) {
    case 'EACCES':
      console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
      console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
}

function onListening() {
  var addr = server.address();
  var bind = typeof addr === 'string'? 'pipe ' + addr : 'port ' + addr.port;
  console.log('Listening on ' + bind);
}
```

Comment: what exactly is the problem then?

Comment: There is a lot scattered and conflicting information. Is it needed to include the SIGINT and SIGTERM handlers in production? Do I need to actually include an uncaught exception handler? What about tracking and cleaning up sockets?  DO use use process.exit(), process.exit(0), or process.exit(1), and where exactly and why? These are all questions to which there are no consistent answers

Comment: Did you ever find answers to your questions? It would helpful to others who find this question looking for the same answers you were.